# IdentityModel.OidcClient migration from 3.1.2 to 4.0 in UWP App

Tags: uwp, openid-connect, windows-10-universal, identitymodel, oidc-client

I have recently updated the nuget package of IdentityModel.OidcClient from version 3.1.2 to 4.0.
Now I get errors on my existing implementation due to missing properties and couldn't figure how to migrate from XXX to 4.0.

```
                return new OidcClientOptions
                {
                    Authority = "https://qawebsvr.boardpac.local:450", //Case Sensitive!
                    ClientId = "boardpac.main.windows",
                    Scope = "openid profile email offline_access",
                    Flow = OidcClientOptions.AuthenticationFlow.AuthorizationCode,
                    RedirectUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().AbsoluteUri,
                    ResponseMode = OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.Redirect,

                    Browser = new WabBrowser(enableWindowsAuthentication: false)
                };
```

In the new v4 of the nuget some properties of `OidcClientOptions` such as `Flow`, `ResponseMode`, `AuthorizeResponseMode`, `AuthenticationFlow` are not recognized. Any help on migrating to v4 is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer in GitHub's repo issue section. According to them, they have removed the hybrid flow (`OidcClientOptions.AuthenticationFlow.Hybrid`) and support only `AuthorizationCode`. Please refer to the links below for further information.

[GitHub.com/IdentityModel - "Setting ResponseMode as OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.FormPost in v4.X"](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient/issues/325)

> **@leastprivilege** (2021-07-07): I removed hybrid and form-post in favour of staying closer to the RFC.

[GitHub.com/IdentityModel - "IdentityModel.OidcClient migration from 3.1.2 to 4.0 in UWP App"](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient/issues/343)

> **@leastprivilege** (2021-11-07): I removed hybrid flow - it will now always do code flow with redirect response mode.